# jquery shopping cart delete table row from local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, shopping-cart

I'm trying to delete a row from a shopping cart (and the local storage) when I hit the 'x' button.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for (i=0; i<numCart; i++){

    var button = $('<td>'+infoCartItems[i].button+'</td>').addClass("checkoutTitles");
    button.text('x');
    row.append(button);
    $(".cartTable").append(row);

}
```

here is what i have for my storage code:

```
var newItem= new Bun(pack, current, flavor2nd, flavor3rd, money);
var existingCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsArray"))||[];
existingCartItems.push(newItem);
localStorage.setItem("itemsArray", JSON.stringify(existingCartItems));
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: currently, when i hit the 'x' nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I used to delete the item from my shopping cart:

```
$(".remove").on('click', function() {

// get the index of the row in the table
var index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
index = index - 1;

// remove item from table
$(this).parent().parent().remove();

// remove item from the cart local storage
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsArray"));
cart.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem("itemsArray", JSON.stringify(cart));
location.reload();
```

});